# invalid schema element named "User" at path "OperationC->columns->relations

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

When I try to build model, I get this error :

> invalid schema element named "User" at path  "OperationC->columns->relations

Here is my schema.yml :

```
Contact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: contact
  columns:

    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fonction_organisme:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    categorie:
      type: string(300)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    region:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    province:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    adresse:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel1:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel2:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel3:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel4:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fax:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    ville:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    journal:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    commentaire:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fix:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    image:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Evenement:
      local: id_contact
      foreign: id_contact_event
      type: many
    Users : 
      class :   User
      refclass : Operation_contact
      foreignAlias : Contact  
Courrier:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: courrier
  columns:
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    annee:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_c:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    exp:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    dest:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: string(10)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    objet:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    image_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_recep:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    date_env:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    type_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations : 
    Users : 
      class : User
      refclass : Operation_c
      foreignAlias : Courriers
Evenement:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: evenement
  columns:
    id_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    action:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_contact_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contact:
      local: id_contact_event
      foreign: id_contact
      type: one
OperationC:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_c
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation_c:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op_c:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations : 
      User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
      Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
OperationContact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_contact
  columns:
    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations : 
      User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
      Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    adresse_user:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tel_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    login:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of mistake in your `schema.yml`:

- `reclass` should be `refClass`.
- you put some bad indentation to some `relations` (this is the error you described)
- there are some mistake in naming table/relation (for `Operation_contact` and `Operation_c`)

Here is your working and fixed `schema.yml`:

```
Contact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: contact
  columns:

    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fonction_organisme:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    categorie:
      type: string(300)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    region:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    province:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    adresse:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel1:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel2:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel3:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel4:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fax:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    ville:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    journal:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    commentaire:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fix:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    image:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Evenement:
      local: id_contact
      foreign: id_contact_event
      type: many
    Users :
      class :   User
      refClass : OperationContact
      foreignAlias : Contact
Courrier:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: courrier
  columns:
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    annee:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_c:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    exp:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    dest:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: string(10)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    objet:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    image_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_recep:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    date_env:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    type_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations :
    Users :
      class : User
      refClass : OperationC
      foreignAlias : Courriers
Evenement:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: evenement
  columns:
    id_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    action:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_contact_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contact:
      local: id_contact_event
      foreign: id_contact
      type: one
OperationC:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: OperationC
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    OperationC:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op_c:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations :
    User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
    Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
OperationContact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: OperationContact
  columns:
    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations :
    User : { onDelete : CASCADE }
    Courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    adresse_user:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tel_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    login:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```